# How to antidifferentiate with a fraction?

Tags: calculus

Full problem: $\frac{3}{\sqrt[5]{2}} + {\sqrt[4]{x}} - {\sqrt[]{x}}$

$\frac{1}{x^{2/5}}$

Supposedly, the answer is $\frac{5x^{3/5}}{3}$. I don't understand how. If I use the anti-diff power rule, doesn't that mean I add one to the exponent, which would make the exponent 7/5, instead of 3/5?

Comment: $\frac{1}{x^{2/5}}=x^{-2/5}$ could help

Comment: I think there's a whole lot of words (and probably other stuff) from the problem that you've neglected to show here. Simply saying $$ \frac{1}{x^{2/5}}$$ in a vacuum does not constitute a problem that can even _have_ right or wrong answers.

Comment: Well, I added the full problem to the OP. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **always true** that for *any* $\;-1\neq n\in\Bbb R\;$ we have

$$\int x^n\;dx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$$

Why is this so? Because the derivative of the right side is the integrand. As simple as that, and then we have

$$\int\frac{dx}{x^{2/5}}dx=\int x^{-2/5}dx=\frac{x^{-2/5+1}}{-\frac25+1}+C=\frac53x^{5/3}+C$$

Comment: Why does the x^2/5 become negative?

Comment: $\frac{1}{x^n} = x^{-n}$. (so, $1/x = x^{-1}$, $1/x^{2/5}  = x^{-2/5}$.)

Comment: @user6050977 As already answered by Maximilian, these are basic exponents laws. Anybody trying to tackle integrals should be proficient in these and even more advanced things, otherwise studying this stuff is going to be a real pain.